# Could this prevent overflow in Java?

Tags: java

I was coding a problem in TopCoder. In one calculating step there could be overflow for, the analysis says the solution is cast too long. I don't understand why this would work.

```
int normalize(int pos) {
    return (int) (((long) pos % MODULO + MODULO) % MODULO);
}
```

The variables `pos` and `MODULO` could both be from the range -2147483648 and 2147483647
I'm wondering what's the help of casting to long? thanks!

Comment: It allows you to capture values outside of the normal `int` range, then when you cast back down to an `int`, values outside of `-2^32` and `2^32-1` are rounded down or up respectively.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, `long`s are always 64-bit quantities. When arithmetic is performed with two quantities of differing widths, Java's specification says that the arithmetic is done with the larger datatype.

Thus, by casting `pos` to a `long`, all subsequent arithmetic is done using 64-bit `long`s. Since the last step is to mod against a 32-bit value, the result can fit within 32 bits for sure, so the final cast loses no precision.

Answer (score 2):

I think it becomes clearer if you refactor the code a little and keep every expression in its own line.

> The var `pos` and `MODULO` could both be from the range -2147483648 and 2147483647

Notice that, precisely: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` == `2147483647`. Taking the edge case (`pos` and `MODULO` as big as possible) is a good example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("result: "
            + normalize(Integer.MAX_VALUE-1, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("result: "
            + normalizeWithoutLongCast(Integer.MAX_VALUE-1, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
}

static int normalize(int pos, int MODULO) {
    System.out.println("normalize()");
    long mod = pos % MODULO;
    System.out.println("mod: "+mod);
    long sum = mod + MODULO; // this is where the overflow can occur
    System.out.println("sum: "+sum);
    return (int) (sum % MODULO);
}

static int normalizeWithoutLongCast(int pos, int MODULO) {
    System.out.println("normalizeWithoutLongCast()");
    int mod = pos % MODULO;
    System.out.println("mod: "+mod);
    int sum = mod + MODULO; // this is where the overflow can occur
    System.out.println("sum: "+sum);
    return (int) (sum % MODULO);
}
```

Output:

```
normalize()
mod: 2147483646
sum: 4294967293
result: 2147483646

normalizeWithoutLongCast()
mod: 2147483646
sum: -3
result: -3
```

So, as you can see, the problem occurs exactly in the `sum = mod + MODULO;` step.

As `MODULO` can be just about `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, that would mean adding as little as `1` to it would return a value **larger than an integer** (an integer overflow).

As, in the step before (`mod = pos2 % MODULO`), you have that `mod` can be `1`, the overflow can occur.

Casting to `long` will allow the sum to happen without fearing the overflow. Of course, the cast would be a problem if we wanted the result to be an `int`.

Luckily, that is not an issue here because the last expression's value (`sum % MODULO`) is between `0` and `MODULO`. And as `MODULO` can be at most `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (`2147483647`) it is then a valid integer and thus safe to be casted back to `int`.